# Is there a formula for estimating confidence intervals for indirect inference estimates?

Tags: simulation, method-of-moments, generalized-moments

Indirect inference is usually deployed to estimate parameters $\theta$ of simulation models, i.e. models for which likelihood is unknown or intractable but that can be "run forward" relatively easily.
In practice it works by running an "auxiliary" model on the real data outputting parameters $\beta$, and then applying the same auxiliary model on simulated data to obtain $\hat \beta (\theta)$ (i.e. the estimated auxiliary model parameters $\hat \beta$ when the simulation parameter is set to $ \theta$ ).
Finally one just keeps changing $\theta$ until the distance between $\beta$ and  $\hat \beta (\theta)$ is minimized.

Now, already in Gourieroux et. al (1993), it was shown that for certain assumptions this estimation is consistent and asymptotically normal.
I am however struggling to find exactly how to compute asymptotic confidence intervals and standard errors in practice.
Is the formula or code for these available anywhere?

Gourieroux, Christian, Alain Monfort, and Eric Renault. "Indirect inference." Journal of applied econometrics 8.S1 (1993): S85-S118.

Comment: Can you add (as an edit to the post) some reference for *indirect inference*?

Comment: What is $\hat{\beta}(\theta)$? I guess that it refers to an estimate $\hat{\beta}$ based on data generated with specific $\theta$, but you might clarify that better.

Comment: hopefully the new wording clariefies this

Comment: While you are on it. Would you mind adding some detailed description of the indirect inference method on wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirect_inference

Comment: I don't see an ungated version of this paper but from the abstract " A second step, based on simulations, provides a consistent and asymptotically normal estimator of the parameter of interest." Is this second step what you're describing above? If you've got this, then is this not saying that your estimator follows a normal distribution? Does your estimate for the variance not come directly from the distribution of the simulations?

Comment: How does this differ from any other simulative estimation techniques, specifically bootstrap or Gibbs sampling?

Comment: @num_39 - small revision to your comment... "... estimator follows an *asymptotically* normal distribution".